# oracle sql detect changes in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Hello i need to detect changes in a table.
To be more specific i need to detect changes in a subquery.

Lets say i have a user Table FOO with a key persnr

```
select distinct persnr,(select max(ora_rowscn) 
from FOO where persnr = A.persnr) from FOO A
order by persnr;
```

But as far as i know the ora_rowscn pseudocolumn is not very precise.
And that is what i experienced. When i change rows for a specific persnr
the ora_rowscn might be the same on various rows even with a different persnr.

how can i detect changes on a specific persnr ?

Comment: I'd recommend to use an additional column `lastUpdate` that is set to `SYSDATE` by a trigger on update of each row.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns007.htm) says:

> `ORA_ROWSCN` reflects the system change-number (SCN) of the most recent change to a row. This change can be at the level of a block (coarse) or at the level of a row (fine-grained). The latter is provided by row-level dependency tracking. Refer to `CREATE TABLE ... NOROWDEPENDENCIES | ROWDEPENDENCIES` for more information on row-level dependency tracking. In the absence of row-level dependencies, `ORA_ROWSCN` reflects block-level dependencies.

So unless you [created your table with `ROWDEPENDENCIES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#CJAEEGDA) your query will find all rows in the same block as the most recently updated row.

As you're already aware, even at row level this is an approximation. If you're relying on an accurate picture of when rows were updated, as Trinimon mentioned you can add a `last_updated` column, probably as a timestamp rather than a date for greater precision, and then set that automatically with an insert/update trigger.

That would also allow you to see when a row was updated, even some time later, though that may not be useful for you. You can convert `ORA_ROWSCN` to to a timestamp for the SCN, but only for a limited period. Explicitly storing the exact time means you won't have to worry about that.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks so far. I guess the ora_rowscn wouldn't be precise enough to determine which row was actually updated. I tried this approach and get a new ora_rowscn for rows that weren't updated at all. So i guess i try the last_updated appreach with a trigger. i thought oracle might provide this kind of information for me.

Comment: @ZSchneidi - right, other rows in the same block as one that was updated. With row dependencies enabled you wouldn't see that.

Comment: ok this would be a good approach. As far as i read it is not possible to enable the ROWDEPENDENCIES on an already created table. And i have to use a tool to create my tables wheter i like it or not. So i guess is have to stick to the trigger approach. Thanks for your help Alex

Answer (score 0):

For each row, `ORA_ROWSCN` returns the conservative upper bound `system change number (SCN)` of the most recent change to the row. This `pseudocolumn` is useful for determining approximately when a row was last updated.

```
select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) from SOMETABLE
```

The above query will give the timestamp where the row was updated. My output is like below

```
SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)
-------------------------------
1/13/2015 12:29:00.000000000 AM
1/13/2015 1:23:47.000000000 AM
```

so i hope you will understand

Comment: That seems to be from [the 10g docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm), and you missed the next part that says it's normally at block level - so another row in the same block will appear to have been updated too. [The 11g docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns007.htm) make this a bit more explicit.